# How to simulate a dataset with a binary target in proportions determined 'a-priori'?

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, logistic, simulation

Can someone tell me what is the best way to simulate a dataset with a binary target?

I understand the way in which a dataset can be simulated but what I'm looking for is to determine 'a-priori' the proportion of each class.
What I thought was to change the intercept to achieve it but I couldn't do it and I don't know why. I guess because the average is playing a trick on me.

```
    set.seed(666)
    x1 = rnorm(1000)       
    x2 = rnorm(1000)

    p=0.25 # <<< I'm looking for a 25%/75%
    mean_z=log(p/(1-p))

    b0 = mean( mean_z - (4*x1 + 3*x2)) # = mean_z - mean( 2*x1 + 3*x2)
    z = b0 + 4*x1 + 3*x2  # = mean_z - (4*x1 + 3*x2)  + (4*x1 + 3*x2) = rep(mean_z,1000)
    mean( b0 + 4*x1 + 3*x2 ) == mean_z # TRUE!!

    pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))     
    y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)  
    mean(pr)  # ~ 40% << not achieved
    table(y) # 0:759 - 1:421
```

What I'm looking for is to simulate the typical "logistic" problem in which the binary target can be modeled as a linear combination of features.

These 'logistic' models assume that the log-odd ratio of the binary variable behaves linearly. That means:

```
log (p / (1-p)) = z = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 where p = prob (y = 1)
```

Going back to my sample code, we could do, for example: z = 1.3 + 4 * x1 + 2 * x2 , but the probability of the class would be a result. Or instead we could choose coefficient b0 such that the probability is (statistically) similar to the one sought :

```
log (0.25 / 0.75) = b0 + 4 * x1 + 2 * x2
```

This is my approach, but there may be betters

Comment: Oh no ! The devil's number !

Comment: maybe that's why!

Comment: This seems very complex. Are you just trying to generate a data set with a given proportion of 0 & 1?  That can be achieve much more simply with `S = sample(0:1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.75))`  If that is not what you are looking for,  please make it clear what your desired output would be.

Comment: Thanks @G5W. What I'm looking for is to simulate the typical "logistic" problem in which the binary target can be modeled as a linear combination of features.

Comment: Actually, these 'logistic' models assume that the log-odd ratio of the binary variable behaves linearly. That means:  `log (p / (1-p)) = z = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2` where `p = prob (y = 1)`.  

Going back to my sample code, we could do, for example: `z = 1.3 + 4 * x1 + 2 * x2` , but the probability of the class would be a result.
Or instead we could choose coefficient b0 such that the probability is (statistically) similar to the one sought :`log (0.25 / 0.75) = b0 + 4 * x1 + 2 * x2`. 
This is my approach, but there may be betters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion is the coefficients you have used are very large. They correspond to odds ratios of 55 and 20. Unless you have specific reasons for doing this, $\ln(4)$ and $\ln(3)$ are probably more appropriate arbitrary choices.

The problem with your data simulation is you are only specifying the predicted probability when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are zero. This is easy to verify. Run your logistic regression model, and apply `plogis()` (inverse logit function) to the intercept coefficient. You will arrive at .25.

The issue is the transformation from logits to probabilities is non-linear. In your example, $$.25 = (1+e^{-\bar{z}})^{-1} \neq \mathrm{E}\big[(1+e^{-z})^{-1}\big]$$ as you observed.

I might approach your example problem using the latent variable approach. In this model, we assume:

\begin{equation}
y^* = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \epsilon \quad\mathrm{and}\quad
y =
  \begin{cases}
  1, & \mathrm{if}\ y^* > 0\\
  0, & \mathrm{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon \sim L(0, 1)$, $x_1\sim N(0,1)$, and $x_2\sim N(0,1)$ keeping with your approach.

With this approach, we can readily manipulate $\mathrm{E}[y]$ by changing the intercept. So we can re-write the equation as:

\begin{equation}
y =
  \begin{cases}
  1, & \mathrm{if}\ \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \epsilon > -\beta_0\\
  0, & \mathrm{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Since the equation is additive on the logit scale, we can assume the quantity, $\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \epsilon$, converges to normality. The variance of such a distribution would be: $\beta_1^2 \times 1^2 + \beta_2^2 \times 1^2 + \pi^2/3$, $\pi^2/3$ is the variance of $L(0, 1)$.

If we want the proportion of 1's to be 25%, we can set $-\beta_0$ to the 75th percentile of a normal distribution with the variance above. The mean of this distribution would be: $\beta_1\times \bar{x}_1 + \beta_2 \times \bar{x}_2$. In our example, that would be 0. So $-\beta_0$ would be the 75% percentile of $N(0, \beta_1^2 \times 1^2 + \beta_2^2 \times 1^2 + \pi^2/3)$. Following my own recommendation, I use $\ln(4)$ and $\ln(3)$ as $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

In R syntax, this would be:

```
set.seed(666)
b0 <- qnorm(.25, sd = sqrt(log(4) ^ 2 + log(3) ^ 2 + pi ^ 2 / 3))
res <- t(replicate(2500, {
  x1 <- rnorm(1000)
  x2 <- rnorm(1000)
  z <- b0 + log(4) * x1 + log(3) * x2
  y <- rbinom(1000, 1, plogis(z))
  c(mean(y), unname(coef(glm(y ~ x1 + x2, binomial))))
}))
# The first element is the mean of y
# Others are regression coefficients
colMeans(res)
# [1]  0.244050 -1.718929  1.397497  1.109592
```

Here's a more complicated example to see if it still works:

\begin{equation}
y =
  \begin{cases}
  1, & \mathrm{if}\ x_1 + 1.5 \times x_2 + .25 \times x_3 + \epsilon > -\beta_0\\
  0, & \mathrm{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $x_1\sim N(1, 1)$, $x_2 \sim N(0, 1)$ and $x_3 \sim \mathrm{Bern}(.5)$.

In this example, I want the mean of $y$ to be 10%. So $-\beta_0$ would be the 90% percentile of $N(1 + .25 \times .5, 1 + 1.5^2 + .25 \times .5 ^ 2 + \pi^2/3)$:

```
b0 <- -qnorm(.9, 1 + .25 * .5, sqrt(1 + 1.5 ^ 2 + .25 ^ 2 * .5 * .5 + pi ^ 2 / 3))
res <- t(replicate(2500, {
  x1 <- rnorm(1000, 1)
  x2 <- rnorm(1000)
  x3 <- rbinom(1000, 1, .5)
  z <- b0 + x1 + 1.5 * x2 + .25 * x3
  y <- rbinom(1000, 1, plogis(z))
  c(mean(y), unname(coef(glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, binomial))))
}))
# The first element is the mean of y
# Others are regression coefficients
colMeans(res)
# [1]  0.0964992 -4.4560205  1.0125437  1.5117373  0.2611867
```

I hope this helps. I have tested it a couple of times and it appears to do a decent job. This is one approach I attempted that worked not so badly.

---

**EDIT:** The normal approximation requires that there are many additive features with none having an inordinate influence on the latent variable relative to others. If you simulate a large number of variables, then it works relatively well.

```
set.seed(12345)
mean(replicate(10000, {
  X <- matrix(rnorm(10000), 100)
  target <- qnorm(.25, 0, sqrt(ncol(X) + pi ^ 2 / 3))
  mean(y <- rbinom(nrow(X), 1, plogis(target + X %*% rep(1, ncol(X)))))
}))
# [1] 0.249637
```